# pausing a shell script till previous command finishes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script which has a qsub command follwed by other command which depend on the output of the qsub command. I have a shell script which looks like

```
qsub <my_jobs>
cat <some_files>
grep <some_pattern>
```

I want the qsub to finish running before the script goes to the cat command. I put "wait" after the qsub, but did not work.

Comment: Does any of your commands end with `&`?

Comment: no, none of the commands end with a '&'

Comment: So probably your `qsub` command is a kind of a dispatcher, which "sends" new jobs to the background and exits. The real problem needed to be solved here is to find how to make "qsub" wait until its dispatched jobs return

Comment: Or at least, how to get the process id of the job started by `qsub` in order to wait on it.

Answer (score 4):

Add "-sync y" to the qsub command line.

From the manual in: http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html

> ```
>  -sync y[es]|n[o]
>       -sync y causes qsub to wait for  the  job  to  complete
>       before  exiting.   If  the  job completes successfully,
>       qsub's exit code will be that of the completed job.  If
>       the job fails to complete successfully, qsub will print
>       out a error message indicating why the job  failed  and
>       will  have  an exit code of 1.  If qsub is interrupted,
>       e.g. with CTRL-C, before the  job  completes,  the  job
>       will be canceled.
>       With the -sync n option, qsub will exit  with  an  exit
>       code of 0 as soon as the job is submitted successfully.
>       -sync n is default for qsub.
> ```